# Include begin{document}, end{document} in LaTeX tables code generated in Stata

Tags: stata

While using **estpost/esttab/esttab** in Stata to generate LaTeX tables, latex initialization syntax such as **documentclass{}**, **begin{document}**, and  **end{document}** are never included. This means that every LaTeX code generated needs for these to be added.

I have many many tables to create. Is it possible to include these through Stata itself?

Comment: Sounds like a sensible default to me: how many tables are documents with nothing else before or after? Seems to me that editing in these instructions is just as easy as running a program to do it, but undoubtedly any programmer could write their own small routines.

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential solutions, the first is to include these using the `prehead` and `postfoot` options, which allow you to do this directly, but make table formatting a bit more difficult. Or there is the option to simply use `include{asdf.tex}` in another file.

Solution 1 example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

reg price mpg

esttab using "temp.tex", ///
    prehead("\documentclass{article}\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}\begin{document}\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}") ///
    postfoot("\end{tabular}\end{document}") ///
    replace
```

This will make a basic table, but doing things like including a title become more difficult with this option.

Second solution, in a tex file, you can include any number of tables thusly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{any_tex_file.tex}
\input{any_tex_file2.tex}
\end{document}
```

and in this way you can include all of your tables.

Hope this helps

Comment: The prehead postfoot is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution could be including this command into your stata esttab output commands

```
booktabs page(column)
```